# Implementation of socket.io (client side) logic on server side (php, sockets)

Tags: php, sockets

Following snippet works perfectly on client side.

```
var socket = io.connect('EXTERNAL_DATA_SOURCE');  // Connect to the socket.

socket.on('connect', function() {
    // Perform some computations when connection is established.
    socket.emit('add', [1, 2, 3, 4]);
    console.log('Socket connected');
});

socket.on('update', function (data) {
    // Perform computations when some "update" arrives from the server.
    // "data" contains required info.
});
```

My goal is to implement the same logic on server side (php, sockets).
A daemon process needs to interact with exactly the same 'EXTERNAL_DATA_SOURCE'.
I've tried to use "elephant.io" , connected to the socket and "emits" an event.
My question is how can I implement a "listening" using php?

```
use ElephantIO\Client;
use ElephantIO\Engine\SocketIO\Version0X;

$strUrl  = 'EXTERNAL_DATA_SOURCE';
$client  = new Client(new Version0X($strUrl));
$client->initialize();
$client->emit('add', [1, 2, 3, 4]);

// How to implement a listening?
```

Comment: Try:

`while(true) {$data = $client->read(); $client->keepAlive(); }`

Comment: Thanks Ernestas, but, unfortunately, $client->keepAlive(); is not yet supported by ElephantIo...